# How to get data from zookeeper znode without all the metadata?

Tags: apache-zookeeper

When I connect to the zookeeper-server and do `get /data` I get a bunch of metadata along with the data I'm looking for.

```
MyData
cZxid = 0xa
ctime = Mon May 11 14:29:57 UTC 2020
mZxid = 0xa
mtime = Mon May 11 14:29:57 UTC 2020
pZxid = 0xa
cversion = 0
dataVersion = 0
aclVersion = 0
ephemeralOwner = 0x0
dataLength = 14
numChildren = 0
```

I am wondering if there is a way to retrieve ONLY the data withotu using the java api? Is there any kind of rest api that I could use to get this done?

Answer (score 1):

For ZooKeeper CLI client get can be called with the `-w` flag to get only the actual data without any metadata of the a znode.